# Desktop gadet/app for Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-desktop-gadgets

I want to make a desktop gadget like the Sticky notes that we have but just with some additional functionality.
Now that the gadgets have been discontinued in windows, i am not sure about what technology to use to create this app.
I want to create a custom UI like just a Add button on the side of the desktop and clicking on it would create notes.
I was trying to use node-webkit but seems that will appear like a web page and not what I want. Can anyone tell me what should i use to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

A Node Webkit window doesn't have to look like a webpage. You can use a frameless window and then design the UI to look however you want with HTML and CSS.

[Frameless Window](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Frameless-window)